# QT CMAKE based application unexpected finished

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I am using QT Creator to open an existing CMAKE based project on Windows 10, after managing to get it compiled and build pass, I start to run it. However it crashed without anything can be seen.　The weird thing is I could not even to debug it, breakpoint set to

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

in main.cpp would not stop anything.  I am really new to QT and CMAKE, I am looking for help on how/what to for now. BTW, I do not even see a dmp file or error log file.

I am using 
QT Creator 4.11.1
MinGW 7.3.0 64 bit
CMake 3.17

Comment: Does the application rely on custom dll's? If you run your executable in the explorer (ie browse to it and then double click), do you get an error message?

Comment: yes, there is error message saying - The application was unable to start correctly, Click OK to close the application @delins

Comment: That's not the error message I was hoping for :). My money is on a problem in the code. It may have run correctly before, but perhaps that was on a different OS and/or compiler? We'll need to see the code to help with that. Also, to debug with QT Creator in Windows you have to choose "Start debugging... " and press the "retry" button when the exception dialog pops up.

Comment: Thanks @delins I will update code tomorrow